# Querystring is dropping after VF page reloads on error

Tags: visualforce

When a VF page is reloaded automatically as a result of an error, it drops the query string from the URL. How do I change this behavior and ensure the query string remains in the URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can try using rerender instead of form submit.

Use the form id in rerender attribute of the button to avoid refreshing the URL. If there is a error, it will stay on the same page, else it will redirect which you need to handle.